# Jersey unmarshal JSON: Last element null does not work

Tags: json, jersey, unmarshalling

I am using Jersey to parse the following JSON:

`{"response":{"status":"OK","campaigns":[{"id":12345,"state":"active","code":null}]}}`

But I get the following error message:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No more parsing elements.`

If I switch the position of the fields code and state so that the resulting JSON looks like

`{"response":{"status":"OK","campaigns":[{"id":12345,"code":null,"state":"active"}]}}`

everything works fine. Also if I change the *code*-field in the first JSON to a *non-null* value like `"code":"test"`, Jersey can parse this without any problems. I tried other more complex examples always getting the above mentioned error message when leaving the **last field** of any element of an array *null*.

I think I am doing something wrong, because I could not find any others having the similar problem. I already tried to implement a CustomJAXBContextResolver using other JSON notations like *natural* but nothing worked for me.

Any ideas?

---

Here are my binding classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoadEntityResponse {

public LoadEntityResponse() {
}

private Response response;

public Response getResponse() {
    return response;
}

public void setResponse(Response response) {
    this.response = response;
}
}
```

and

```
public class Response {

public Response() {
}

private String status;
private String error;
private String error_id;

private Campaign[] campaigns;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getError() {
    return error;
}

public void setError(String error) {
    this.error = error;
}

public String getError_id() {
    return error_id;
}

public void setError_id(String error_id) {
    this.error_id = error_id;
}

public Campaign[] getCampaigns() {
    return campaigns;
}

public void setCampaigns(Campaign[] campaigns) {
    this.campaigns = campaigns;
}
}
```

and finally

```
public class Campaign{
public Campaign() {
}

protected int id;
protected String code;
protected String state;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCode() {
    return code;
}

public void setCode(String code) {
    this.code = code;
}

public String getState() {
    return state;
}

public void setState(String state) {
    this.state = state;
}
}
```

**Solved:** Using JacksonJsonProvider now:

```
...
DefaultClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
...
```

that´s all!

Comment: This is a bug in Jersey (http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1459) and it will be fixed in version 1.16. As you mentioned the problem arises if the last JSON field has null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Jackson POJO support that comes with `jersey-json` but there is a need to do some configuration, see [POJO support](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section) in [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html).

Comment: Thank you. I´m using JacksonJsonProvider now and it´s working fine for me. It´s a pity that Jersey can not handle that on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Genson http://code.google.com/p/genson/.
To enable it on client side use the following code:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getClasses().add(GensonJsonConverter.class);
cli = Client.create(config);
```

**EDIT**: on server side there is no configuration needed, when the jar is in your classpath json support is automatically enabled.

Comment: Thank you, I tried JacksonJsonProvider before and it works fine.